# How to reliably generate A4 printable label

Tags: php, html, printing

For a project I'm working on we need to let the user print an A4 (landscape) label with a few dynamic pieces of information on it.

Currently we outputting the label in HTML but this has the following draw backs:

- poor browser support - IE in particular doesn't render things at the right locations and it ends up printing on 2 pages. Firefox doesn't print the larger images, only the smaller ones.
- auto header and footer - think all browsers add this and not all users know how to turn it off
- guesswork with margins as each printer handles it differently

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: you want something absolute such as pdf

Comment: There is no single HTML attribute or CSS property that will magically make all of your pages print nicely, but the problems you listed have been addressed in other posts on this site. Your best bet is to do a separate search for each of them, here or on Google. Keyword hints: @page rule, wkhtmltopdf, princexml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy solution to cross browser render differences. As Dagon suggested, the best option is to generate a PDF, image or something that's not HTML and will not be rendered by the browser directly.

Note about:

> auto header and footer - think all browsers add this and not all users know how >to turn it off

You can clear the default padding and margin by CSS:

```
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up using FPDF and FDPI to load a template PDF and write my own text to it.